# Questions about $f(n)=3+\frac{12}n$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Experimental Psychology:

To study the rate at which animals learn, a psychology student performed an experiment in which a rat was sent repeatedly through a laboratory maze. Suppose the time in minutes required for the rat to traverse the maze on the $n$th trial was approximately

$$f(n)=3+\frac{12}n$$

a) What is the domain of the function $f$?

b) For what values of $n$ does $f(n)$ have a meaning in the context of the psychology experiment?

c) How did it take the rat to traverse the maze on the $3$rd trial?

d) On which trial did the rat first traverse the maze in $4$ minutes or less?

e) According to the function $f$, what will happen to the time required for the rat to traverse the maze as the number of trial increases? Will the rat be able to traverse the maze in less than $34 minutes?

My answers are

a) $n \ne 0$

b) $0<n<100$

Am I right?

Comment: For part b, what does it mean by 'have a meaning in the context of the psychology experiment?'

Comment: Why limit the number of trials to $n<100$? You could reasonably say: 'any positive integer that's not absurdly large' and leave it at that.

Comment: This is not a calculus problem. I changed the tags to better reflect the problem.

Answer (score 2):

a) Correct.

b) Why is the 100 there? The experiment may take longer than 100 trials. You probably just need $n$ to be a positive integer, so "$0<n$ and $n \in \mathbb Z$" or "$n \in \mathbb Z+$" or "positive integers" seems better.

c) Just substitute $n=3$ into the formula and calculate. You should be able to do this yourself.

d) Set the formula equal to 4 and solve for $n$. You should be able to do this yourself.

e) As $n$ increases, the time required to traverse the maze decreases. To see if 3 minutes is possible, set the formula equal to 3 and solve for $n$. If you get a possible solution that is a positive integer, the rat will be able to traverse the maze in 3 minutes. Otherwise, the rat cannot do it. You should be able to do this part of the problem yourself.

Comment: For part b), $n$ is the number (ordinality) of the trial, not the time it takes. You probably meant that the experiment may require $100$ or more trials, so...

Comment: @Deepak: Oops, you are right. I'll edit my answer. Thanks for the catch!

Comment: Part b) should be: set the formula to $4$ and solve for $n$.

Comment: @Ritz: You mean part d), but you are right. I was *sure* that I had typed in 4! I guess I am a bad proofreader of my own work. Thanks for the catch!

Comment: Hehe, we both seem to make typos. I guess it means we are still human.

Comment: In a psychology course, you should probably say "positive integer" and not mention "$\mathbb Z$".

Comment: @GEdgar: Good point. I have edited my answer. Thanks!